# Summing $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |1- e^{{2\pi ik}\over {n}}| $

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

I need to sum$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |1- e^{{2\pi ik}\over {n}}| $$ which finally reduces to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2\sin\ {{\pi k} \over {n}}.$$

But I'm stuck here.The final answer is supposed to be $n$ .

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: I did, but got some weird answers.

Comment: What are the weird answers?

Comment: 2.cot(pi/2n), yeah just one answer,no 'answers' .

Comment: I reached at the same value. Why is it weird?

Comment: Because the answer is supposed to be 'n'.

Comment: Well, unless I made a mistake, for $\,n=3\,$ we have

$$\left|1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right|+\left|1-e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\right|=2\left|\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i\right|=\sqrt{9+3}=2\sqrt 3\neq 3$$

so your claim is not true...Check this, either you or I are wrong.

Comment: To be honest the original question asked me to prove that the sum of the distances of the points $e^{{2\pi ik}\over {n}}$ k=1,2,...(n-1) (on a unit circle) from 1  was equal to n .

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, then there's no doubt: the claim's false since, say in the example I gave above, the three roots of unit form an equilateral triangle, so the distance you're looking for is just the length of any of its sides, which is $\,\sqrt 3\,$ ...the claim comes closer to be true if instead you want the sum of their distances from the origin, but then it is trivially true that the sum of **all** this distances (up and including $\,1\,$) is $\,n\,$ ...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2\sin\ {{\pi k} \over {n}}=2\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{ik\pi/n}\right)$$
and we can sum the terms of geometric sequence.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question should be the value of the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left (1-e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}} \right ) =
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}} =
n - \frac{1-e^{2\pi i}}{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}} = n$$

The last equality follows because $e^{2\pi i}=1$.